# Library for android, Set as wallpaper fitted to screen

Tags: android, bitmap

Is there any library that i can use in android for wallpaper. I want my bitmap set as wallpaper and fitted to its screen device

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

Bitmap yourbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

try {
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(yourbitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: use android:scaleType="centerCrop" as an xml attribute on the imageview where your declaring.. this is all what u need to achieve the purpose; if ur looking for image view frameworks u can use **Glide**; :)

Comment: what i mean is set wallpaper in Home Screen of android phone